# How node and runtime are connected?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, substrate-node

When we run a `substrate` client `cargo run -- --dev` we run a `substrate-node`. The business logic is defined on the pallets composed by `construct_runtime!` inside the runtime. So which part of the [node](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/main/node) is responsible for initiating and interacting with the runtime?

Answer (score 1):

In a Substrate client, such as when running `cargo run -- --dev`, the responsibility for initiating and interacting with the runtime lies with the node itself. The node is the main component that handles the execution of the blockchain network and manages the runtime.

When you run the Substrate client, it starts the node, which includes the consensus engine,networking, block production, and Transaction Processing.
Runtime contains the core business logic of the blockchain. It consists of a set of pallets, which are reusable modules that define the state, storage, and behavior of the blockchain. The runtime is responsible for executing the transactions, maintaining the state of the blockchain, and processing the system events.

So, the node is responsible for initiating the runtime and coordinating its interaction with other components. It ensures that the defined business logic in the pallets is executed correctly and maintains the integrity of the blockchain network.

Comment: Yes, the node does the connection with runtime. I was curious to know which part of the node does that. The runtime is compiled into wasm. So, which part of the node loads/makes communication with the wasm?

Answer (score 0):

Substrate provides a [FRAME](https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start/substrate-at-a-glance/#what-is-frame) based blockchain system for adding custom pallets to make a application specific blockchain. To achieve this a custom runtime is also required which will interact with custom pallet.

> How node and runtime are connected?

You can find connection between node and runtime by going through [node/src/service.rs](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/service.rs) and [node/src/chain_spec.rs](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs) file, `service.rs` file contains the logic for the spawn of the network and `chain_spec.rs` file contains the genesis configuration for the chain.

---

[Here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/87b1b4728e29f68c6b2bafde7f3d0f4c8af9b302/node/src/service.rs#L33-L34) you can see the type `FullClient` is taking `RuntimeApi` as one of its generic input as you can see in below code snippet.

```
pub(crate) type FullClient =
    sc_service::TFullClient<Block, RuntimeApi, NativeElseWasmExecutor<ExecutorDispatch>>;
```

Than this is used by[spawn_tasks](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/87b1b4728e29f68c6b2bafde7f3d0f4c8af9b302/node/src/service.rs#L208) `client` field, you can find `spawn_tasks` definition [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c32f5ed2ae6746d6f791f08cecbfc22fa188f5f9/client/service/src/builder.rs#L404-L550), there is a method [gen_rpc_module](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c32f5ed2ae6746d6f791f08cecbfc22fa188f5f9/client/service/src/builder.rs#L518C6-L530) in `spawn_tasks` which than is using the client to as its input and you can find its definition [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c32f5ed2ae6746d6f791f08cecbfc22fa188f5f9/client/service/src/builder.rs#L618-L730). I hope this helps.

Comment: So how does the node interact with the runtime?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas `service.rs` file calls `RuntimeApi` which directly interacts with runtime of the chain and `service.rs` works hand in hand with the client side.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta could you help me with where exactly `service.rs` calls the `RuntimeApi` ? I was going through https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/service.rs but couldn't find

Comment: @AbishekBashyal sure will update my answer